# tried to login using the rest api but i get error 400

Tags: rest, login

> grant_type—Value must be password for this flow.
>   client_id—Consumer key from the connected app definition.
>   client_secret—Consumer secret from the connected app definition.
>   username—End-user username.
>   password—End-user password

I am sending the above details to the https://mydomain/services/oauth2/token with headers content-type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded but still i get the below response

```
{
    "error_description": "grant type not supported",
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Double check against that you are sending the `Content-Type` header as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and that you are encoding the parameters correctly. I.e. Note that the @ in the email becomes %40.

Here is a working example I did using [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) in Chrome.

Raw POST body:

> grant_type=password&client_id=3MVG9iTxZANh12345678901234567890X9eYLSx.q6x8yD3Q.IT3nRSYXxzGpQqhw5m7nxK6aBxXH70ZH84cV&client_secret=
>   5912345678901234567&username=daniel.ballinger%40mycompany.com&password=somePasswordWithSecurityToken

[image]

Comment: i am doing the same but still it gives me the error ,do i have to set anything on salesforce,infact i treid exactly on postman.

Comment: I assume you used your App "Consumer Key" as the `client_id` and "Consumer Secret" as the `client_secret`? Are you working against a Sandbox or Production/Dev org?

Comment: What OAuth Scopes have you selected? I have: "Access and managed your data (api)", "Provide access to your data via the Web (web)", and "Perform requests on your behalf at any time (refresh_token, offline_access)" on my Connected App.

Comment: Access your basic information (id, profile, email, address, phone)
Access and manage your data (api)
Provide access to your data via the Web (web)
Full access (full)
Access and manage your Chatter data (chatter_api)
Provide access to custom applications (visualforce)
Perform requests on your behalf at any time (refresh_token, offline_access)
Allow access to your unique identifier (openid)
Access custom permissions (custom_permissions)
these are the scopes m using

Comment: @KartikMarujolla Are you working against a Sandbox or Production/Developer org? I.e. what is the sub domain you see when logged into Salesforce with a browser?

Comment: I'm getting the same "unsupported_grant_type" error, and after adding the Content-Type header (as well as trying many, many other fixes), it still doesn't work from the context of my AngularJS app, yet it works just fine when I paste the same request/parameters into Postman or call the request using cURL.

Comment: @JLewkovich Are you able to capture the raw request that you AngularJS app is POSTing?

Comment: @DanielBallinger yes and I've added all the relevant details here: http://pastebin.com/8Lyqbgjn

I would greatly appreciate you looking through this and giving your thoughts. I have a feeling the proxy is causing some sort of information loss, and I don't know how to determine that through Express.JS. I do know that if I cURL the `services/oauth2/token` url without any parameters, I get this same `unsupported_grant_type` error

Comment: @DanielBallinger I've opened this issue as a separate question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/85349/getting-unsupported-grant-type-error-when-using-angular-js-app-expressjs-pro